# Charged Black Hole: Self-Discharge

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, thermal-radiation

Palti writes in his [introduction to the swampland](http://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06239) (page 39) that a charged black hole (BH) could discharge itself, when the Hawking temperature

$$
T_H=\frac{R_+-R_-}{4\pi R_+^2}
$$

($R_+$ and $R_-$ the outer and inner horizons of the BH) is bigger than the mass $m$ of the charged particle with charge $q$, because then the particle can be thermally produced. The electric field of the BH induces a chemical potential, which favours the production of particles with opposite charge wrt the BH charge.

Now my question is: how can a single particle be produced thermally? I thought only pair production is allowed?! Otherwise, e.g. lepton-numbers would not be conserved or other conserved quantum numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
While writing the question I found the answer: The idea is that the particle with opposite charge falls into the black hole (BH), decreasing the BH charge, whereas the other particle escapes. So, it actually *is* pair production.

Comment: If $T<m$ pair production might occur due to the Schwinger mechanism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect